# window.clientWidth is always 0 in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need the actual pixel clientWidth of the document's containing window in IE in order to calculate a proper zoom value but find that the window always returns a value of 0.  Is there a way to get this value from any DOM object?  I'm a JS noob and have discovered that document.body.clientWidth does the trick as long as the zoom is 100 percent, but otherwise returns zoomed pixel values.  Help?

Comment: Are you in strict mode or quirks mode?  I can't remember what all doesn't work under quirks.

Comment: clientWidth refers to a document element, not the window. You can use document.documentElement.clientWidth to come close to window.innerWidth value.

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer earlier than version 8, it retrieves the width in physical pixel size, while from version 8, it returns the width in logical pixel size.

What does it mean?

If the browser is not at the normal zoom level (the user has the ability to zoom in or out a web page: CTRL and +, CTRL and -), the clientWidth property works differently from version 8 than in earlier versions.

- The width is calculated in the default pixel size in Internet Explorer before version 8 even if the current pixel size in the document is different.
- From Internet Explorer 8 and in Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, the width is calculated in the current pixel size.

For example, if the zoom level is 200%, the clientWidth property retrieves two times greater values before version 8 than from version 8 for the same client window size.

For a cross-browser solution to get the size of the browser window:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // always return 1, except at non-default zoom levels in IE before version 8
        function GetZoomFactor() {
            var factor = 1;
            if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect) {
                // rect is only in physical pixel size in IE before version 8 
                var rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
                var physicalW = rect.right - rect.left;
                var logicalW = document.body.offsetWidth;
                // the zoom level is always an integer percent value
                factor = Math.round((physicalW / logicalW) * 100) / 100;
            }
            return factor;
        }

        function GetWindowSize() {
            var zoomFactor = GetZoomFactor();
            var w = Math.round(document.documentElement.clientWidth / zoomFactor);
            var h = Math.round(document.documentElement.clientHeight / zoomFactor);
            var info = document.getElementById("info");
            info.innerHTML = w + "px * " + h + "px";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetWindowSize ()">Size of the browser's client area:
<span id="info" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>

    <div
    style="width:500px; height:1000px; background-color:#e0a0a0;">Size of this element: 500px * 1000px</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which is one of many reasons why I always say you can never, EVER trust IE to do ANYTHING right.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer.  I had tried using document.documentElement.clientWidth originally, but it always returns 0.  I'm on IE9 and having to modify someone else's HTML/JS and this type of thing is why I've avoided this kind of work all of my life.

Comment: Ooops, not done.  Your example DOES work on my browser.  However, if I copy your js and html into the file I'm working with, the returned value is 0x0.  I confirmed that clientWidth is 0 again when requested within your code.  I'm told this html I'm working with is authored strangely.  That is likely the problem.  I'm going to punt this issue, but your answer is greatly appreciated.